# Adding a resource to WPF application causes build error

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working through the book Head First C# and consistently have issues when adding resources to a window. This is a 100% repeatable error on any new WPF application I create when adding a new resource. The only way around this is to comment out the resource, build, and uncomment, as detailed in MVCE below. Images are included as proof this isn't a what-if or theoretical scenario.

What are the proper steps to add a resource file and use it within a WPF project?

I'm using **Visual Studio Community 2017: Version 15.9.9**
Target framework: **.NET Framework 4.6.1**

---

MVCE:

1. Create a new WPF application. Add a class:

   ```
   //MyDataClass.cs
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace XAMLBuildErrorExample
   {
       class MyDataClass
       {
           public string Foo { get; set; }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Within MainWindow.xaml add a resource

   ```xml
   <Window x:Class="XAMLBuildErrorExample.MainWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XAMLBuildErrorExample"
           mc:Ignorable="d"
           Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
       <Window.Resources>
           <local:MyDataClass x:Key="exampleResource" />
       </Window.Resources>

       <Grid>

       </Grid>
   </Window>
   ```
3. Attempt to build. Error "The tag 'MyDataClass' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:XAMLBuildErrorExample'. Line 11 Position 10.":

   [image]
4. Comment out the resource. Build succeeds:

   [image]
5. Uncomment resource. Build succeeds whereas it failed before:

   [image]
6. Any subsequent cleaning of the solution makes building impossible because of the error in the first image.

Comment: Attempted the steps on VS 2017 15.9.6, no errors

Comment: No problems on VS 2017 15.9.5.

Comment: Are you sure that `MyDataClass` and `MainWindow` are both in same assembly？If not，add “;assembly=right assembly name” to the namespace declaration.

Comment: @Alex.Wei Yes, they are in the same assembly. I gave it a shot and added `;assembly=XAMLBuildErrorExample` but still couldn't build.

Comment: No repro VS Community 2017 15.9.4

Comment: No repro VS Community 2017 15.9.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem is tied to initial computer.

Tested on another work station VS Community 2017 version 15.9.11 and build was successful without any issues. Build>Clean>Build without issues.